# Getting error when building iOS app by using EAS (Expo Application Services)

Tags: ios, firebase, react-native, expo

I am creating an Expo app, which I plan to publish to the app store. I have published it to the Android store so far. When I build the iOS app using EAS, I get this error, which is coming from Swift Pods, which is seemed to have been caused by Firebase.

> Error: [!] The following Swift pods cannot yet be integrated as static
> libraries:
>
> The Swift pod `FirebaseCoreInternal` depends upon `GoogleUtilities`,
> which does not define modules. To opt into those targets generating
> module maps (which is necessary to import them from Swift when
> building as static libraries), you may set `use_modular_headers!`
> globally in your Podfile, or specify `:modular_headers => true` for
> particular dependencies.

I honestly have no idea what this error even means, and how to fix it. Anyone here have an idea?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I actually did find a solution to the problem.

What you have to do is install an Expo package called `expo-build-properties.`

```
npx expo install expo-build-properties
```

From there, you include the package in the `plugins` section of your `app.json` file, along with some iOS setting. Here is a code sample:

```
"plugins": [
  "@react-native-firebase/app",
  [
   "expo-build-properties",
    {
     "ios": {
        "useFrameworks": "static"
      }
    }
  ]
]
```

Comment: I am having this same issue please can you provide detail steps on how to fix it

Comment: You are replying to the solution.

Comment: I'm sorry I am asking this here instead of starting my own question

Comment: `Path to GoogleService-Info.plist is not defined. Please specify the `expo.ios.googleServicesFile` field in app.json.` I get this error when I try this fix